# Replace do loop with array notation in fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I would like to replace the following do loop with FORTRAN's intrinsic functions and array notations.

```
do i=2, n
  do j=2, n
     a=b(j)-b(j-1)
     c(i,j)=a*c(i-1,j)+d(i,j)
   end do
end do
```

However, as c(i,j) depends on c(i-1,j) none of following trials worked. Because they do not update c(i,j)

```
!FORALL(i = 2:n , j = 2:n ) c(i,j)=c(i-1,j)*(b(j)-b(j-1))+d(i,j)
!FORALL(i = 2:n) c(i,2:n)=c(i-1,2:n)*(b(2:n)-b(1:n-1))+d(i,2:n)
!c(2:n,2:n)=RESHAPE(   (/(c(i-1,2:n)*(b(2:n)-b(1:n-1))+d(i,2:n),i=2,n)/), (/n-1, n-1/))
!c(2:n,2:n)=RESHAPE((/(((b(j)-b(j-1)) *c(i-1,j)+d(i,j)  ,j=2,n),i=2,n)/), (/n-1, n-1/))
!c(2:n,2:n)=spread(b(2:n)-b(1:n-1),ncopies = n-1,dim=1) * c(1:n-1,2:n) +d(2:n,2:n)
```

This is the best I can get. But it still has a do loop

```
do i=2, n
     c(i,2:n)=c(i-1,2:n)*(b(2:n)-b(1:n-1))+d(i,2:n)
end do
```

Could all do loops be replaced by intrinsic functions and array notation. Or could this one be replaced somehow ?

Comment: after messing with it a bit I think your "best" is indeed the best you can do.  (precomputing an array `a=b(2:n)-b(1:n)` outside the loop might help performance depending on how smart your compiler is..)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to eliminate `do` loops?

Comment: @KyleKanos Actually it is a homework question which I do not know how to answer as I tried a lot of methods to replace the do loop.

Comment: @AlexGao: I added an answer, hopefully it suits your needs ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, nothing beats the traditional do-loop. All the extension intrinsics create memory and CPU overhead by copying stuff to temporary space (on the stack usually), reshaping and the sort. If you're manipulating large arrays, you may encounter out-of-memory issues with the intrinsic functions.

Your best option is to stick to a 2-d loop that has the indexes correctly laid out:

```
do i=2, n
  e = c(1:n,i-1)
  do j=2, n
     a=b(j)-b(j-1)
     c(j,i)=a*e(j)+d(j,i)
   end do
end do
```

By replacing the indexes (and making sure your dimension declarations follow), you are saving on the memory paging. c(j,i) and d(j,i) references travel column-wise inside memory while c(j,i-1) would have cut across columns (and produced paging overhead). So we copy it to a temporary e array.

I think this will be the fastest....

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is very nice to know by doing this can let it run faster.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with

```
do i=2, n
   do j=2, n
      a=b(j)-b(j-1)
      c(i,j)=a*c(i-1,j)+d(i,j)
   end do
end do
```

we can quickly eliminate the `do` loops with some nifty use of `SIZE`, `SPREAD` and `EOSHIFT`:

---

```
res = SPREAD(b - EOSHIFT(b,-1),2,SIZE(c,2))*EOSHIFT(c,-1) + d
```

---

Aha, turns out that the error I was receiving (V1) was due to my using `RESHAPE` rather than `SPREAD`. I fixed this in the current version (V2) and it compiles & works with both `ifort` and `gfortran`.

Comment: could you send me your testing code.In my code, It does not provide same answer as do loop.

Comment: Now the deadline has passed and the teacher did not provide an answer without any do loop. Actually he provided my "best answer" So it seems not all do loop can be eliminated.